# Confused about passing argument via custom functional object

Tags: c++, class

For now, I'm trying to make a little graphic class from custom class with two fields:

```
struct Prog {
    Prog(int y, const string& s) :yy{ y }, name{ s }{}
    Prog() :yy{0}, name{"none"} {}
    int yy;
    string name;
};
```

Then I create my functional object, to convert argument to coordinates value:

```
class Scale {
public:
    Scale() : cbase{ 40 }, vbase{ 1960 }, scale{ 20 }{};
    int operator()(const int y) {
        return cbase + (y - vbase) * scale;
    }
private:
    int cbase;
    int vbase;
    double scale;
};
```

And this is my Graphic class:

```
class Prog_shape :public Shape {
public:
    Prog_shape(const Prog& p) :txt{ {sc(p.yy),240},p.name }, cir{ {sc(p.yy),244},10 } { }
    void draw_lines() const {
        txt.draw();
        cir.draw();
    }
private:
    Graph_lib::Text txt;
    Scale sc;
    Graph_lib::Circle cir;
};
```

And the function that is filling the Shapes container from `vector<Prog>`:

```
void generate_figures() {
    for (auto p : p_vec) {
        sh_vec.push_back(new Prog_shape{ p});
    }
}
```

And now I'm really confused about my `Prog_shape` class's `txt` object, I can't get the value from the `Scale` func object, while the `cir` object can. When I take a few moments to debug, I find values passed to the `txt` constructor are 0. How can it be possible when the values must be the same?

Comment: Show the definition of `Shape` too - or better, make a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like Prog_shape constructor uses `sc` before that member variable is constructed.  That won't end well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i think is no matter,cuz Text and Circle are both subclases of Shape. And when i pass direct expression like `40+(1960-2010)*20 ` instead of     `sc(p.yy)`  in txt initialization,it's work's properly.

Comment: @Eljay OMG. Im so Sorry,lot of Thanks! Thats my carelessness,and stuck eyes. That's why i love C++. God bless Stroustrup and all of you.